# Xpath Query Won't Return Results

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I'm trying to return some results from an Xpath query but it won't select the elements correctly. I'm using the following code:

```
public function getTrustPilotReviews($amount)
{
    $trustPilotUrl = 'https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/purplegriffon.com';
    $html5 = new HTML5;
    $document = $html5->loadHtml(file_get_contents($trustPilotUrl));
    $document->validateOnParse = true;
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
    $reviewsDomNodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@id="reviews-container"]//div[@itemprop="review"]');
    $reviews = new Collection;

    foreach ($reviewsDomNodeList as $key => $reviewDomElement)
    {
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($reviewDomElement->ownerDocument);

        if ((int) $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="ratingValue"]')->item($key)->getAttribute('content') >= 4)
        {
            $review = [
                'title'     => 'Test',
                'author'    => $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="author"]')->item($key)->nodeValue,
                'date'      => $xpath->query('//*[@class="ndate"]')->item($key)->nodeValue,
                'rating'    => $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="ratingValue"]')->item($key)->nodeValue,
                'body'      => $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="reviewBody"]')->item($key)->nodeValue,
            ];

            $reviews->add((object) $review);
        }
    }

    return $reviews->take($amount);
}
```

This code won't return anything:

```
//div[@id="reviews-container"]//div[@itemprop="review"]
```

But if I change it to:

```
//*[@id="reviews-container"]//*[@itemprop="review"]
```

It partially works but does not return the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Viper-7, biberu and salathe in the ##php IRC I have this working now using:

```
public function getTrustPilotReviews($amount)
{
    $context = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false)));

    $url = 'https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/purplegriffon.com';
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $reviews = new Collection;

    foreach($xpath->query('//div[@id="reviews-container"]/div[@itemprop="review"]') as $node)
    {
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $rating = $xpath->query('.//*[@itemprop="ratingValue"]', $node)->item(0)->getAttribute('content');

        if ($rating >= 4)
        {
            $review = [
                'title'     => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(descendant::*[@itemprop="headline"]/a)', $node),
                'author'    => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(descendant::*[@itemprop="author"])', $node),
                'date'      => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(descendant::*[@class="ndate"])', $node),
                'rating'    => $xpath->evaluate('number(descendant::*[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content)', $node),
                'body'      => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(descendant::*[@itemprop="reviewBody"])', $node),
            ];

            $reviews->add((object) $review);
        }
    }

    return $reviews->take($amount);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the changes are, in addition to working code?

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand all the changes and I'm still learning xpath. That said, essentially I've scrapped the use of https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php and used DOMDocument directly. There's also the use of contextnode within the queries as not to search the entire document but only within the returned $node. Then I use evaluate as mentioned in ThW's answer.

Comment: DOMDocument::loadHtml() loads the source as HTML 4, makes all node names lowercase and removes any namespace.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're using the [HTML5-PHP](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php) library. If you do you need to use namespaces. The library loads HTML5 into an XHTML document. You can test that if you save the DOM document as XML. The output will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
```

So if you use XPath you need to register and prefix for the XHTML namespace and use it for element names.

```
...
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

$reviewNodes= $xpath->evaluate(
  '//x:div[@id="reviews-container"]//x:div[@itemprop="review"]'
);
foreach ($reviewNodes as $reviewNode) {
  ...
}
...
```

You have an condition inside the loop that can be part of the outer XPath used to fetch the reviews:

```
$expression = 
  '//x:div[@id="reviews-container"]
   //x:div[
     @itemprop="review" and 
     (.//*[@itemprop = "ratingValue"]/@content > 4)
   ]'
```

Do not use `DOMXPath::query()` but `DOMXPath::evaluate()`, it allows you to get scalars directly. The second argument for the methods is the context node. Use relative locations paths (without a `/` at the start of the expression).

```
 ...
 foreach ($reviewNodes as $reviewNode) {
   $review = [
     'title' => 'Test',
     'author'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(.//*@itemprop="author"])', $reviewNode),
     'date'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(.//*[@class="ndate"])', $reviewNode),
     'rating'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(.//*[@class="ratingValue"])', $reviewNode),
     'body'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(.//*[@class="reviewBody"])', $reviewNode)
   ];
   ...
 }
```